# python manage.py syncdb

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am very new to python and Django, was actually thrown in to finish off some coding for my company since our coder left for overseas.

When I run python manage.py syncdb I receive the following error

psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "winepad"

I'm not sure why I am being prompted for user "winepad" as I've created no such user by that name, I am running the sync from a folder named winepad. In my pg_hba.conf file all I have is a postgres account which I altered with a new password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the instructions I left are causing me some issues.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Once you start a Django project, you have to set your database settings in `your_project/settings.py` . The settings you want to check/change is (assuming you use Django 1.3) something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '', 
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

So make sure those settings are correctly set up (you have to do it manually)

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings.py file. The most likely reason for this issue is that the username for the database is set to "winepad". Change that to the appropriate value and rerun `python manage.py syncdb` That should fix the issue.

Comment: Aminho's answer clarifies where to set the value for username, in case you are still a little lost.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, it was that simple. Once I read the settings.py file a little closer I noticed that it was pointing to info in the localsettings.py file. Changed the value and it worked. Once again thank you.